# Do we stop getting reputation of 2 points from edits after crossing 2000 rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation, suggested-edits

Earlier my edit suggestions when accepted fetched me 2 points. Now I have crossed the 2000 rep, I don't get 2 rep points on edit.

Is this normal?

Comment: When you have 2K+ reputation you have full edits privileges, the edit is instant and doesn't go through any review. The +2 is only for edit that goes through review process and approved i.e. found to be good. With 2K rep, the system assume all your edits are good but no worry, you can still get some badges for editing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looking at our handy [What is reputation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) page, it has the following:

> - suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)

and nothing else regarding edits. Thus, it would seem that we do not get reputation for edits once we pass the 2000 reputation mark, since they aren't "suggested" anymore (they don't go through the Suggested Edits queue), they're just made.

---

**EDIT:** As pointed out by Szymon and him056, tag wiki edits need approval until you hit 20k reputation. What I said above only applies to edits to questions and answers; tag wiki edits are still "suggested" before you hit 20k reputation, and thus will still carry the +2 (unless of course, you've hit your 1000 reputation cap)

Comment: BTW the reason you have mentioned has nothing to do with the quote you have added. :)

Comment: @hims056 Trying to find a good way to say exactly what I want here. Basically trying to point out that once we hit 2k rep, edits aren't "suggested" anymore, and thus don't get the +2.

Answer (score 3):

You only get +2 rep for edits that were suggested by you and approved by reviewers.

You can still get rep for suggesting edits to tag wikis until you get to 20k rep.

Comment: We get reputation for suggesting edits on tag wikis if we have less than 20K reputation.